# rails controller action routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, action

I'm looking to "automatically" generate routes based on actions defined in a controller.  resources routing (as far as I know) only automatically generates routes & helpers for http verbs.  In this instance I'm serving mostly static pages using rails and have no need for http verbs in my controller.

Specifically:

In a controller I have defined actions which refer to those mostly static pages.

```
def action
end
```

In the routes file I have a bunch of

```
match "/url" => 'controller#action'
```

I'd like all those matched routes to be generated automatically based on the actions in the controller.  Something CONCEPTUALLY along the lines of:

```
for actions in controller.erb do |action|
    'match "/action" => "controller#action"
end
```

Is this possible?  Would I write the code in the routes file directly?

I also have some nested actions to consider... a controller action may be:

```
def action
    def nested_action
    end
end
```

I'd appreciate any thoughts on this matter.  Thanks.

Comment: try `match ':action'` inside your resource block...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with the normal [/:controller/:action idea?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes)

That won't deal with nested actions, but... I'm having a difficult time understanding why you'd ever want that.

Comment: I forgot all about that!  That should work fine for 90% of what I need... Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this creates path Helpers (which I like to use).  I'll confirm tomorrow.

Comment: @twinturbotom Of course not; how could it? The controllers and actions are arbitrary.

Comment: @twinturbotom (Are you sure, though? I honestly don't remember.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
controller :controller_name do
   get "path/action" => :method_name, :as => :path_action
   post "path/save" => :method_name, :as => :path_save
end
```

That is, you can group different routes within a controller using the method above.